# How to use powershell to open a URL like "imacros://run/?m=my_saved_macro.iim"?

Tags: powershell, imacros

To open a typical URL like `http://www.google.com` from PowerShell, we can use something like:

```
start http://www.google.com
```

However, to automate [imacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox), sometimes I need open URLs like `imacros://run/?m=my_saved_macro.iim`. You can go to [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox) if you want the details.

When I try the PowerShell code `start imacros://run/?m=my_saved_macro.iim`, I got the following error:

```
start : This command cannot be run due to the error: Unknown error (0x80041002).
At c:\temp\test.ps1:51 char:5
+     start "imacros://run/?m=$macro_file_name";
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I want to know how to open this kind of URL in the default browser from PowerShell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `Start-Process` cmdlet like so:

```
Start-Process $URI
```

If you need even more control, you can go into the .NET API for Process and use one of the modifications of this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($URI)
```